# Mapping database model to Ui model

Tags: android, kotlin, mapping, android-room

I try to make the project based on clean architecture so that each layer could have its own data model.
I have a database that contains 2 Entities: "movie" and "details".

```
@Entity(tableName = "movie")
data class MovieDbModel(
    var page: Int,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int,
    var poster_path: String,
    var overview: String,
    var original_title: String)

@Entity(tableName = "details")
data class DetailsDbModel (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: Int,
    val genres: Genres,
    val runtime: Int,
)
```

I want to map those 2 entities to 1 UI model "MovieAndDetailsUi " and convert it to MutableList that I will use for liveData.

```
data class MovieAndDetailsUi (

    val page: Int,
    val id: Int,
    val poster_path: String,
    val overview: String,
    val original_title: String,
    val genres: List<GenreUi>,
    val runtime: Int,

    )
```

But I have problems with that. Could you please show me the best way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73396023/android-room-modeling-1-to-0-1-relationships. The bottom line is that you're better off just using a flat structure from the start, with a single model that MovieAndDetails

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map those two you could create a companion object on the `MoviesAndDetailsUi` class that takes both entities and combines them, for example

```
data class MovieAndDetailsUi (

    val page: Int,
    val id: Int,
    val poster_path: String,
    val overview: String,
    val original_title: String,
    val genres: List<GenreUi>,
    val runtime: Int,
) {
    companion object {
       fun fromDatabaseEntities(movie: MovieDbModel, details: DetailsDbModel) {
            return MovieAndDetailsUI(
                page = movie.page,
                id = movie.id,
                poster_path = movie.poster_path,
                overview = movie.overview,
                original_title = movie.original_title,
                genres = details.genres,
                runtime = details.runtime
            )
        }
    }

}
```

That way on your view model you could just get the data from the DB and map it to the UI class, for example:

```
fun getMovies(): MutableList<MovieAndDetailsUi>() =
   viewModelScope.launch() {
      withContext(Dispatches.IO) {
          val movies: List<MovieDbModel> = ... // Access the DB and get the movies
          val details: List<DetailsDbModel = ... // Access the DB and get the details

          val zipData = movies.zip(details) {movie, detail -> Pair(movie, detail)}
          val mappedData = zipData.map { pair -> MovieAndDetailsUi.fromDatabaseEntities(pair.first, pair.second) }.toMutableList()
          liveData.postValue(mappedData)
      }
   }
```

I also agree that in this case you should go with the flat structure on the entities as you can skip the mapping and also avoid having multiple classes with the same attributes basically, but in case you want to go this way here's how. Also, I don't know how you are associating the details and movie table and how you query the tables, you might have a problem there too as there's no foreing key on movies referencing to details or vice versa. I added the `zip` function just for the example but you should have a proper way to associate the movies and the details objects

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me a lot. 
I have a relation between the movie and details: https://dropmefiles.com/rjsaU
I need to think. Maybe I need to change the way I query movie and details lists. Maybe do it in a single query - https://dropmefiles.com/yUsFV